# How would you translate Enchanté?

Tags: single-word-request, phrase-request, french

The French word *Enchanté* means "Nice to meet you" or "Delighted". What is the most idiomatic way to say this in German? Google Translate gives *verzauberte* but I doubt this is idiomatic.

Comment: https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/enchanté translate it as _Ich freue mich, Sie kennen zu lernen._, [dict.leo.org](https://dict.leo.org/französisch-deutsch/enchante) offers also some translations.zösisch-deutsch/enchante

Comment: "Sehr erfreut" used to be a classical greeting until the 70ies/80ies, which was basically a literal translation. If you insist, you can still use it today in the same contexts as "enchanté". It's just about as aged as the French.

Comment: *verzauberte* isn't just not idiomatic I would wait a moment if there comes more and after 1-2 secounds I would look very confused, because I would be deeply confused. Janka's *Angenehm* works in pretty much all situations even if it can be seen as old-fashioned sometimes. tofro's *Sehr erfreut* feels not only old-fashioned but also abit more formal. I wouldn't use *Sehr erfreut* in less formal situations e.g. getting introduce to a friend of a friend by the first mentioned friend in a pub I wouldn't response with *Sehr erfreut* but especialy in the north of germany that may be seen different.

Comment: @ikadfoanhfda: Maybe that's a regional thing, but *angenehm* feels considerably more dated to me than *sehr erfreut*. Maybe because the latter is at least close to the more natural "[Es] freut mich, dich/Sie zu treffen", as opposed to the old-fashioned-sounding "[Es ist mir] angenehm, dich/Sie zu treffen".

Answer (score 8):

In the exact same situations the French would have used "Enchanté", in German you would (have) used

> Sehr erfreut

(without anything added). This is a near-literal translation (with French level of enthusiasm translated to German reserve, though...) that used to be the classic greeting, if you would have, for example, been introduced to a female host. This idiom is just about as aged and partially uncommon as the French "enchanté" is. Today, it is only ever used in upper-class environments or very formal occasions.

Answer (score 7):

> Angenehm!
>
> Angenehm, <your own last name>.

is an old-fashioned way to greet someone who had just been introduced to you. Still appropriate for formal occasions. If you happen to know the person, you are expected to be more chatty.

Comment: Oder "Willkommen!".

Comment: "Willkommen" kann aber nur der Gastgeber sagen. Oder die Gastgeberin.

Comment: Schön, Dich zu sehn. :)

Comment: @userunknown "Schön, dass du auch da bist" (zum Gastgeber)

Comment: „Freut mich“ kann man auch noch als lässigere Variante zu „Angenehm“ und „Sehr erfreut“ ins Rennen schicken.

Answer (score 2):

Weitere Formen, wie man heutzutage das sagen kann, was die Altvorderen mit "Angenehm!" und "Sehr erfreut!" (siehe andere Antworten hier) ausdrückten, wären:

> Schön, dass Sie gekommen sind!
>
> Schön, dass Sie da sind!
>
> Freut mich!
>
> Schön, Sie zu sehen!
>
> Schön, Sie kennenzulernen!
>
> Naaaa?

Es kommt natürlich auf das Szenario an. Kommt jemand gerade zur Tür herein zu einem vereinbarten Treffen? Stellen sich Leute einander vor? In welchem sozialen Umfeld findet das Treffen statt? Beispiele:

1) Man hat jemanden zu einem Gespräch ins Büro eingeladen, den man noch nicht kennt, allenfalls vom Telefon. Der Gesprächspartner kommt herein:

> Gast: Guten Tag, Müller.
>
> Besuchter: Hallo Herr Müller, schön dass Sie gekommen sind!

2) Bei einem Stehempfang steht man in einem Grüppchen herum, und nicht alle kennen sich. Einer, der alle kennt, sagt:

> Allekenner: "Herr Müller, das ist Helga Meier, Frau Meier, das ist Emil Müller.
>
> Helga Meier: Guten Tag Herr Müller, schön Sie kennenzulernen!
>
> Emil Müller: Ganz meinerseits!

3) Sehr informelle Begegnung, sagen wir unter Jugendlichen. Dennis und Sascha stehen im Stadtpark herum, Isabel läuft vorbei.

> Dennis (der Isabel kennt): Hey, Isabel!
>
> Isabel: Hey, Dennis!
>
> Dennis: Hey, das ist Sascha.
>
> Isabel: Hey, Sascha! Naaaa?
>
> Sascha: Hey, Isabel! Naaaa?

Mit dem "Naaaa?" wird Interesse and der Person bekundet sowie Bereitschaft, sich mit ihr weiter aktiv auseinanderzusetzen. Es ist von der kommunikativen Funktion her also weitgehend identisch  mit den anderen vorgestellten Formen.

---

Note on the use of machine translations in general: as a translation for the above "Stellen sich Leute einander vor?" Google Translate provided "Do people imagine each other?". Nice!